# The Saturn pricing model, did it work?

Tags: pricing

Has there been a post-mortem on the Saturn pricing model? For those who do not remember, in the 1990s GM sponsored a new car model, the Saturn, which featured "no haggle" pricing. The car would be sold at one fixed price depending on options.

Anecdotal evidence suggests that the pricing strategy was popular with buyers, but did it work for the company from an economics point of view?